# Error: object...not found in R programming

Tags: r

I am trying to change the the data types of the following columns from character to numeric in a data set called sat_results:

```
sat_results <- sat_results %>%
  mutate(`Num of SAT Test Takers` =  as.numeric(`Num of SAT Test Takers`),
         `SAT Writing Avg. Score` = as.numeric(`SAT Writing Avg. Score`), 
         `SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score` = as.numeric(`SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score`),
         `SAT Math Avg. Score` = as.numeric(`SAT Math Avg. Score`)) %>%
  mutate(avg_sat_score = `SAT Writing Avg. Score` + `SAT Critical Reading Avg. Score` + `SAT Math Avg. Score`)
```

I have the above code in R. If I run it, the result is:

> Error: object 'Num of SAT Test Takers' not found

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you post a sample of your `dataframe` `sat_results`?

Comment: What does `names(sat_results)` return? Sounds like you just have the a column name wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Changing the variable data type is rather easy and you do not need to use mutate.  Suppose you have a 5 variables (columns) data frame with the variables named A-E.  And suppose variable D (column 4) is a factor type variable.  To change df$D into a numeric variable, then you would do as follows:

```
df$D <- as.numeric(df$D)
```

Comment: Hi.  Glad my answer worked out for you.  If you would be so kind, please check the up arrow next to my answer so that I may get credit for answering your question.  Regards,